# CircleProgressIndicator inside LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a catalog app for a design system I'm building using Compose. In this app I'm using `LazyColumn` to display the multitude of states a single component can be in and how it looks. However, a few of the states have within them an indefinite CircleProgressIndicator. It is meant to represent that state while `loading`.

```
private data class ButtonDisplays(
    val name: String,
    val buttonType: ButtonType = ButtonType.PRIMARY,
    val destructive: Boolean = false,
    val enabled: Boolean = true,
    val icon: String? = null,
    val iconSide: IconLocationButton = IconLocationButton.RIGHT,
    val loading: Boolean = false
)

@Composable
fun Buttons() {
    val buttons = listOf(
        // region Primary Buttons
        ButtonDisplays(
            name ="Primary Button"
        ),
        ButtonDisplays(
            name = "Primary Button Loading Right",
            loading = true
        ),
        // etc...
    )

    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = ContentTokens.ContentPadding
    ) {
        items(
            items = buttons,
            key =  { it.hashCode() }
        ) {button ->
            Column {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                Label(text = button.name, style = PulseTheme.typography.tagDefault)
                Divider()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(10.dp))
                DisplayButton(
                    buttonType = button.buttonType,
                    destructive = button.destructive,
                    enabled = button.enabled,
                    icon = button.icon,
                    iconSide = button.iconSide,
                    loading = button.loading
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can essentially assume `DisplayButton` is some form of `Button { CircleProgressIndicator(...) }` as it's not much different than that really.

As you can see I've tried a few different tricks to limit composition, but none of them seem to work. Giving a `key` and surrounding by a stable parent are common responses to recomposition. There is no remembering at these levels.

I do use functions like below to determine these values. Inside there are `LaunchedEffect`s for the `interactionSource` to detect various states as well to be transparent.

```
    val border =
        borderStroke?.border(enabled = enabled, interactionSource = interactionSource)
    val containerColor =
        colors.containerColor(enabled = enabled, interactionSource = interactionSource)
    val contentColor =
        colors.contentColor(enabled = enabled, interactionSource = interactionSource)
    val decoration = textDecoration?.textDecoration(interactionSource)
```

Am I missing a fundamentally basic idea? There have been comments that `List<T>` is itself unstable and any recomposition of a child of a `List` is recomposed to the highest parent, but I don't understand this idea it seems. Is there any way to keep all of the buttons from recomposing or am I just stuck?

Comment: Did you try to use state? `val buttons by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf( ... ))}`

Comment: @bylazy I thought I did try it previously, but I will attempt again now. I will hate if that is the solution.

Comment: Did confirm that does not help the situation.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood the essence of your problem. I think using `mutableStateListOf(...)` insted of `mutableStateOf(listOf(...))` should help you.

Comment: @bylazy yep did all of that. The list still recomposes all elements even ones that don't change :/